# Reference SecurityGroup from another cloudformation template inside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC (created via cloudformation) which creates some common shared infrastructure for all stacks created in that VPC, e.g. ssh jumphost and a security group for the ssh jumphost.

I have a separate cloudformation template to create stacks of Web+App+DB inside the existing VPC.

How do I allow inbound ssh 22 to my instances in my stack template from the common ssh jumphost defined in the first template?

According to the docs, inside a VPC I need to specify `SourceSecurityGroupId`, which must have either the actual VPC ID or use a `Ref` function to find the ID of a Security Group defined in **this** template.

How can I reference an existing SG inside the same VPC but from another template?

EDIT:

Same question for outbound via a NAT instance. NAT instance is provided at VPC level, but each stack needs its security group to allow outbound access to **just** the NAT Instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: This has changed since my original answer. See also the answer below by Vor that suggests using [custom resources and Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) to allow cross-stack references.

**Original Answer**

There is no support to refer to resources from another stack so you cannot use `Ref()`. You can use `SourceSecurityGroupId` (as you suggested) and pass it as a [parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/concept-parameters.html), and/or you can use [`SourceSecurityGroupName`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-ingress-sourcesecuritygroupname). But Cloudformation can't programmatically refer to the other stack.

I like to write Cloudformation templates using Python, boto and the [troposphere library](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) to work around problems like this in code.

Comment: So you are saying I can do one of: explicitly enter the ID as a parameter; hardcode the ID in the template; or use `SourceSecurityGroupName`. Can I even use `SourceSecurityGroupName`? The docs say, "for instances in a VPC, specify the SourceSecurityGroupId property."

Comment: How does doing this in python solve it? You still need to generate the template. Or do you use boto to retrieve the desired GroupId and then enter it into the template?

Comment: My mistake, you're correct that you can't use `SourceSecurityGroupName` in a VPC. And yep, I use boto to find the group ID. So like I said, there's no support for cross-VPC referencing.

Comment: So if I want it as plain vanilla cloudformation template, best bet is either hardcode the ID in the template (feh) or ask for it as a parameter?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Those are your options unless you do it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. For the scale of what I am doing, I will work with those.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the previous answer would be to create a [CustomResource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). You can have a service running on EC2 that is subscribed to the SQS queue. Once CFN will reach the `CustomResource` it will send SNS notification to the topic you gave. Then your service will receive a notification, process request and respond back.

There is also a library that can help you a lot with setting up your `custom service` https://github.com/aws/aws-cfn-resource-bridge

Comment: That is cool. So you are using a pub/sub queue to pass the parameters programmatically?

Comment: That's right. You can also set up AWS Lambda function to process requests from CFN and avoid managing your own process/queue

Comment: That is better than doing it in Python or other programming language locally, but I don't want to switch selected answer a year later. I will upvote.

Comment: You can use Lambda to do this? Pretty wild. Is there an example somewhere? Do you have a gist or does AWS have examples with two CFN templates communicating via Lambda?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate that.